# Override ListViewItem Click Event with a Button Click Event Inside It

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `ListView` with a click `EventSetter` that applies to `ListViewItem`s. Inside each `ListViewitem` is a "Delete" button with a click event. Is there a way to separate the button click event so it doesn't trigger the other event? If not, how to implement this?

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvHistoryInput" ItemsSource="{Binding recentInputFolders}" SelectionMode="Single">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                                <Button Content="Delete" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="DeleteItem" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="AddToTextBox" />
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                </ListView>
```

AddToTextBox:

```
private void AddToTextBox(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {

            if (sender is ListViewItem item)
            {
                if (lvHistoryInput.IsMouseOver)
                {
                    txtInput.Text = item.Content as string;
                }
                else if (lvHistoryOutput.IsMouseOver)
                {
                    txtOutput.Text = item.Content as string;
                }
                else if (lvFavouriteInput.IsMouseOver)
                {
                    txtInput.Text = item.Content as string;
                }
                else if (lvFavouriteOutput.IsMouseOver)
                {
                    txtOutput.Text = item.Content as string;
                }
                Utility.GetFilesIn(txtInput.Text);
            }
        }
```

DeleteItem:

```
private void DeleteItem(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    object path = button.DataContext as object;

    foreach (String str in recentInputFolders.ToList())
    {
        if (str == (String)path)
        {
            recentInputFolders.Remove((String)path);
            lvHistoryInput.Items.Refresh();
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have that PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event handler at all, instead of a SelectionChanged event handler on the ListView? Also consider using a ListBox, the base class of ListView. You would use ListView only when you actually set its View property.

Comment: @Clemens I considered using SelectionChanged, but I need an event to be triggered when the same element is clicked again. I'll switch to ListBox, thanks.

Comment: So you are invoking the delete action by a Button, but the other action by a click on the item itself? Seems inconsistent. I'd add another Button.

Comment: It's a history list that shows up after clicking the History button. It makes sense that, when clicked on a specific item in it, its string is copied to Input textbox.

Comment: When you click the button you automatically select the hosting item. This means both event handlers are invoked. It doesn't make sense to interact with the ListViewItem without selecting it. Since you have attached two individual event handlers, each handler has its own context: Button.Click and ListViewItem.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown. They are logically separated. It is not clear what your problem is.

Comment: @BionicCode Sorry, I must have worded it poorly, I'm new at this. To put it in use case scenario, all I wanted is to invoke Delete button function (Deleteitem) without calling the other one (AddToTextBox). I guess that's not possible the way I wanted.

Comment: I understand. But as I wrote before, it doesn't make sense. You want to execute AddToTextBox every time the user clicks on the item. But clicking the button is also clicking the item. You can't click the button without clicking the item. How can this be possible?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Any suggestions how to solve this the other way?

Comment: Impossible to  make any suggestions. I don't know what you are trying to do. You asked for help without giving any context so nobody can suggest you a better solution or workaround. Would you explain what you are trying to do, then somebody can suggest you a better solution. That's how it works. If your concern is the content of the TextBox, then simply clear it (or whatever makes sense) after executing the delete handler. But again, it's absolutely a mystery what you are trying to do and why the current behavior is a problem for you.

Comment: I thought it was clear from the code. Delete button inside each ListViewitem deletes its string from a list of paths (and from the ListView respectively), while clicking on a ListViewItem itself copies it to an input textbox. Right now the functions overlap; as you said, considering the Delete button is inside ListViewItem, it can't be called without executing AddToTextBox, too. So my question is: how to implement these two functions without any interference? Data binding is probably the way to go, but I need to become more familiar with it. I wanted a simple solution for starters.

Comment: In programming there is nothing like "a solution for starters". It's not like advanced programmers chose extra complicated solutions. We always pick the simplest one. First question: why is the SelectionChanged event not suitable? It doesn't matter how often you click on the same item, it's still selected.

Comment: If you recentInputFolders would be a ObservableCollection, removing items is automatically reflected in the ListView. Don't call Items.Refresh() explicitly! It will refresh the complete ListView instead of updating the changed/removed items. Make recentInputFolders a ObservableCollection and remove the Items.Refresh().

Comment: Also don't call recentInputFolders.ToList() - it will create a completely new list ==> bad performance, not required. Use a reverse for loop instead.